# Get current timestamp of video while playing it using ytdb-core

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using `ytdb-core` npm module to play stream to discord via my bot, and I want to get a timestamp of video while playing it,

my code:

```
let dispatcher = await data.connection.playStream(ytdl(data.queue[0].url, { filter: 'audioonly'} ));
```

and then im getting dispatcher object in other file, and executing this file while video playing:

```
console.log(dispatcher.player.streamingData);
// outputs: 

{ channels: 2,
  count: 92,
  sequence: 92,
  timestamp: 88320,
  pausedTime: 200,
  length: 20,
  missed: 0,
  startTime: 1552441690823 }
```

but I don't know how to convert `count` into normal time format, when it's 5s, count = 281, which is not ms nor seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dispatcher.time` returns progress time in ms